keypress events not working on mobile chrome browser
I work with angular 7.
I have this code which is working in desktop with chrome browser.
with this code I can enter only numbers and not more than 4 number.
html code :
 <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form__group btm">
                      <label class="form__label">
                

             numidentity :
        
                      </label>
                     
                <input 
  class="form__input validation-field" 
 [(ngModel)]="this.numidentity"  
 (keypress)="keyPressNumbersIdentity($event)"  
  placeholder=""
  type="text" >
 
               
                    </div>
                  </div>
              

typescript code :
 keyPressNumbersIdentity(event) {
  var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;

  // Only Numbers 0-9
  if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {

    if (event.target.value.length >4) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
    return true;
   }


  } 
}

but when I test the same html page in mobile android chrome browser the (keypress) events not working meaning I can enter characters not only number and more then 4 number.

keypress events are deprecated and may not work consistently across devices, especially on mobile browsers. A better approach would be to use the keydown, input, or beforeinput events.
...
     (input)="keyPressNumbersIdentity($event)"  
...

or:
...
     (keydown)="keyPressNumbersIdentity($event)"  
...
 


thank you for your response, but when I try to test I find that (keydown) not working on chrome desktop

still (input) have worked and u have marked the same answer (about input) that was posted an hour after my solution as an answer... :(

yes (input) work, juste first I tried with (keydown) which caused problem, so your answer give the solution

HTML
<div class="col-12 col-md-6">
  <div class="form__group btm">
    <label class="form__label">
      numidentity:
    </label>
    <input 
      class="form__input validation-field" 
      [(ngModel)]="numidentity"  
      (input)="onInputNumbersIdentity($event)"  
      placeholder=""
      type="text">
     
  </div>
</div>

TS
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  numidentity:string;
  onInputNumbersIdentity(event: Event) {
    const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    
    // Replace non-numeric characters
    inputElement.value = inputElement.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  
    // Prevent entering more than 4 numbers (though maxlength will handle this too)
    if (inputElement.value.length > 4) {
      inputElement.value = inputElement.value.slice(0, 4);
    }
  
    // Update the ngModel manually if needed (optional, if [(ngModel)] is used)
    this.numidentity = inputElement.value;
  } 
  
}

